# Static files on asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, static-files

I am trying to enable static files on an `ASP.NET Core 2.0` web application. I have a bunch of files in a folder called updater which resides outside the `wwwroot` folder. To allow access to them I added

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"TestUpdater")
    ),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Updater")
});
```

This lets a different program to be able to get its files by calling the urls. The issue is all the files need to be downloaded instead of served. There is one txt file. How do I allow only download instead of it being served?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between "serving" and "downloading" files as you describe is that in one instance the browser downloads the file to a temporary location and displays it in the window (inline) while the other the browser will ask a user where to save the file to a permanent location (attachment).

If the other programs you're referring to are contacting the server for these files directly it shouldn't matter. For example using HttpClient, you don't have to change your static file middleware at all.

If you want the browser to prompt the user to save the file even if it's a recognized content type, try setting the Content-Disposition response header to "attachment". To do this from your Startup.cs config, modify your StaticFileOptions to use something like this:

```
new StaticFileOptions()
{
    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
    {
        context.Context.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment";
    }
}
```

Comment: That does it. I actually have a php file in there too, which needs to be executed, and I thought the "serving" was the issue. The problem still persists, is there anything in particular I need to do for the static php file to be allowed to execute?

Comment: @Ratan you need to have PHP running the file for that. Do you have PHP running on the server? (This sounds like a very odd architecture to me.)

Comment: yes, PHP is running as the file executes when served from a non-core site on the same server. Yes, I agree, it is. I plan to change it in the future, but cannot right now, as I am upgrading an existing non-core to a core and need to maintain some of the old files till we actually move them out from there.

Comment: also, what are the benfits of serving these files using UseStaticFiles, and if I have multiple folders, like updater1, updater2, and so on.. do I need to individually call UseStaticFiles for them with the new PathString?

Comment: I guess you answered the current question, and the php part is a new question. I'll close this and ask a new question. Thanks!